# MySql Triggers and performance

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following requirement. I have 4 MySQL databases and an application in which the user needs to get the count of number of records in tables of each of these databases. The issue is that count may change in every minute or second. So whenever the user mouse-hovering the particular UI area, I need to have a call to all these databases and get the count. I don’t think it is a best approach, as these tables contain millions of records and every time on mouse over, a dB call is going to all these databases.

Trigger is the one approach I found. Rather than we are pulling data from the database, I feel like whenever any insert/update/delete happening to these tables, a trigger will execute and that will increment/decrement the count in another table (which contain only the count of these tables). But I have read like triggers will affect database performance, but also read some situation trigger is the only solution.

So please guide me in my situation triggers are the solution? If it affects the database performance I don’t need that. Is there any other better approach for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you have 4 databases and n number of tables in each of them and when the user hovers over a particular area in your application the user should see the number of rows in that table.
I would suggest you to use count(*) to return the number of rows in each table in the database.Triggers are used to do something when a particular event like update,delete or insert occurs in a database.It's not a good idea to invoke triggers to react to user interactions like hovering.If you can tell me in which language you are designing the front end I can be more specific.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename where condition
```

OR

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tablename
   WHERE condition 
   LIMIT 5;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second one is used when you want to limit the results but still return total number of rows found.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution you gave is straight forward. But I am concerned about performance and what I am asking is each mouse over, I am writing this count(*) query to my database is not a good option. This database contain huge amount of record and also used in some other application. My approach was to write a trigger to those table and i will keep the count in another table(table used by my application only). So that i can fetch count easily. But what I am asking is writing trigger is a good option or not

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use count(*). This is inefficient, possibly to the point of causing a table scan. If you can get to the information schema, this should return the result you need sub-second:

```
select table_rows from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'tablename'
```

If you can't for some reason, and your table has a primary key, try:

```
SELECT COUNT(field) FROM tablename
```

...where field is part of the primary key. This will be slower, especially on large tables, but still better than count(*).

Definitely don't use trigger.

Comment: This is not accurate for InnoDB tables. Count(*) is the best approach if your tables are InnoDB, which is the standard nowadays. https://aaronfrancis.com/2022/mysql-count-star-slow